# Integral in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How to solve $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{-e^{it}\,\mathrm{d}t}{-e^{2it} - 1 +2e^{it}}$$
I used substitution and got the same upper and lower limits.

Comment: Because of the tag (complex-analysis) ... can you write this as a contour integral $\int_\gamma f(z)\;dz$ for some closed contour $\gamma$ and some nice function $f$?

Comment: Sure, ∫cf(z)dz, where f(z) = 1/1+z^2 and the c is a circle given by mod(z+i) =i

Comment: You have to use latex. Click on edit  to see latex code.

Comment: I don't think that expression for the denominator is correct - there shouldn't be a +1 in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method without complex analysis, because it turns out to be significantly easier. 
$$\begin{align} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{-e^{it} dt}{-e^{2it}-1+2e^{it}}
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}-2+e^{-it}}dt \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{it/2} - e^{-it/2})^{-2}dt \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}(2i\sin \tfrac{t}{2})^{-2}dt \\
&=-\tfrac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}\csc^2\!\tfrac{t}{2} dt \\
&=\tfrac{1}{2}\left[\cot\frac{t}{2}\right]_0^{2\pi}
\end{align}$$
which diverges, so the original integral does not converge.

Comment: i think there is a mistake in the sign of e^(-it) and 2, otherwise it seems fine, never occurred to me use identity in the denominator

Comment: You're correct, my mistake.

Comment: For the sake of learning, i would still like to know how to solve the anti symmetric integral in this case when the integral limits come out to be the same

Comment: Of course - the problem is that the integral limits shouldn't come out to be the same, a substitution should be a bijective function. I'm not sure which substitution you used, but you could try splitting the range of integration in half and doing it separately each time - I suspect there would be a division by zero otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on B. Mehta's approach:\begin{align*}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-e^{it}\,dt}{-e^{2it}-1+2e^{it}}&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{e^{it}+e^{-it}-2}\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{2\cos(t)-2}\\&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{\cos(t)-1}.\end{align*}Since $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^2}{\cos(t)-1}$ exists and it is a real numebr ($-\frac12$) and since the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{t^2}$ diverges, the last integral diverges too.

Comment: Nice! Cleaner than looking up the antiderivative of $cosec^2$ as well

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above, it seems that you are going to evaluate the complex integral
$$I:=\int_{|z+i|=1} \frac{dz}{1+z^2}.$$
I guess that the path is the circle $|z+i|=1$ because $|z+i|=i$ does not make sense (it is an empty set!).

Since $1+z^2=(z+i)(z-i)$, we have that
$$I:=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z+i|=1} \frac{dz}{z-i}-\frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z+i|=1} \frac{dz}{z+i}=0-\frac{2\pi i}{2i}=-\pi.$$
where we used the fact that
$$\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{dz}{z-a}=\begin{cases}
 2\pi i&\mbox{ if $|a-z_0|<r$,}\\
 0&\mbox{ if $|a-z_0|>r$.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with residue theorem, will apply it when i learn it sorry :(

Comment: I don't think your original $I$ is the same as the integral in the question.

Comment: @Irrational Is $\int_{|z+i|=1} \frac{dz}{1+z^2}$ the integral that you have to evaluate? I edited my anwer and I'm not using Residue Theorem.

Comment: @RobertZ its just Mod(z+i) = i not 1

Comment: @Irrational_Number What is Mod?, The modulus? You mean $|z+i|=i$?

Comment: @RobertZ yes that's what i mean, forgive my editing i'm new and not familiar with it

Comment: @Irrational_Number But $|z+i|=i$ has no sense at all!! The lhs is real and the rhs is imaginary!! Are you sure?

Comment: @RobertZ yes that is the question, i was confused myself

Comment: @Irrational_Number It is typo for sure. Are you using a book? Probably it is $|z+i|=1$. The symbols $i$ and $1$ are similar...